# How to Find the nearest neighbours of a specific type in a matrix

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, matrix, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve a problem in which I am supposed to create a dictionary which has the coordinates of a node marked 1 and its neighbors which are also one(1).This basically is the adjacency list which I need to create in order to implement BFS/DFS on it.

I have tried the same using the setdefault() method as well as using the get() method.I have done this before for some problem but I am unable to remember it.

Here's the code which I have written for the same.

```
n,m=input().split()

n=int(n)
m=int(m)
#q=int(q)

"""User Input Done"""
square=[[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(m)]

neighbour_dictionary={}

#neighbour_dictionary.setdefault(,[])

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        number=int(input("Enter a number"))
        square[i][j]=number

"""Get Initial Number of Nations(1)"""
nation_count=0
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,m):
        if square[i][j]==1:

            try:
                if square[i][j+1]==1 and (j+1)>0 and (i<n) and (j<m):
                    try:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i,j)].setdefault([i,j],[]).append((i,j+1))
                    except KeyError:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i,j)]=[(i,j+1)]

            except IndexError:
                pass
                #print("c1")
                #print((i,j),(i,j+1))

            try:
                if square[i+1][j+1]==1  and (i+1)>0 and (j+1)>0 and (i<n) and (j<m):
                    try:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i,j)].setdefault([i,j],[]).append((i+1,j+1))
                    except KeyError:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i, j)] = [(i+1, j+1)]
            except IndexError:
                pass
            #print("c2")
                #print((i,j),(i+1,j+1))

            try:

                if square[i+1][j-1]==1 and (i+1)>0 and (j-1)>0 and (i<n) and (j<m):

                    try:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i, j)].setdefault([i,j],[]).append((i+1, j-1))
                    except KeyError:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i, j)] = [(i+1,j-1)]
            except IndexError:
                pass
                #print("c3")
                #print((i,j),(i+1,j-1))

            try:

                if  square[i][j-1]==1  and (j-1)>0 and (i<n) and (j<m):

                    try:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i, j)].setdefault([i,j],[]).append((i, j-1))
                    except KeyError:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i, j)] = [(i, j + 1)]
            except IndexError:
                pass
                #print("c4")
                #print((i,j),(i,j-1))
            try:

                if square[i-1][j]==1 and (i-1)>0 and (j)>0 and (i<n) and (j<m):

                    try:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i, j)].setdefault([i,j],[]).append((i-1, j))
                    except KeyError:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i, j)] = [(i-1, j)]

            except IndexError:
                pass
                #print('c5')
            try:
                if square[i+1][j]==1  and (i+1)>0 and (j)>0 and (i<n) and (j<m):

                    try:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i, j)].setdefault([i,j],[]).append((i+1, j))

                    except KeyError:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i, j)] = [(i+1, j)]

            except IndexError:
                pass
                #print("c6")
                #print((i,j),(i+1,j))
            try:

                if square[i-1][j-1]==1  and (i-1)>0 and (j-1)>0:
                    try:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i, j)].setdefault([i,j],[]).append((i-1, j-1))
                    except KeyError:
                        neighbour_dictionary[(i, j)] = [(i-1, j-1)]
            except IndexError:
                pass
                #print("c7")
                #print((i,j),(i-1,j-1))

print(neighbour_dictionary)
```

Do let me know where am I exactly doing wrong.

Comment: @Srini could you help me with this problem?

Comment: No Ji I have no idea sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own Question.There was a Problem with the edge cases that's why it was not working.The conditions which i was using those were wrong.

Thank you everyone for your help.